# Alternative for using `eval()` - Filter products

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, eval

I'm currently trying to build a filter system for within my software and this is what I have below, as you can see i'm using `eval()` and would like a solution where i don't need to use `eval()`, does anybody have any suggestions?

```js
const items = [{
    Product: {
    name: 'Hello',
    which: 1
  },
  Finance: {
    zero: 0
  }
},
{
    Product: {
    name: 'Hello2',
    which: 0
  },
  Finance: {
    zero: 0
  }
}];

const filterMenu = [{
        name: 'text1',
        filterKey: 'Finance.zero == 0',
        subText: false
    }, {
        name: 'text3',
        filterKey: 'Product.which == 0',
        subText: false
}];

const filteredBy = [0, 1];

const filtered = items.filter(e => eval(filteredBy.map(item => "e." + filterMenu[item].filterKey).join(' && ')));
                 
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572). Instead of the `join`, use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: @Bergi - this wouldn't be dynamically accessing properties by variable name, I'm wanting to put the full filter argument e.g. `Product.which == 0` to the object as I'm going to assign this logic within a admin dashboard.

Comment: Just store functions, not strings, in the menu object: `filterKey: arg => arg.Finance.zero == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing your filters as objects instead of strings. This way you can check each `filterKey` via the [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

```js
const items = [
  {
    Product: { name: 'Hello', which: 1 },
    Finance: { zero: 0 },
  },
  {
    Product: { name: 'Hello2', which: 0 },
    Finance: { zero: 0 },
}];

const filterMenu = [
  {
    name: 'text1',
    filterKey: { group: 'Finance', key: 'zero', value: 0 },
    subText: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'text3',
    filterKey: { group: 'Product', key: 'which', value: 0 },
    subText: false,
  }
];

const filtered = items.filter(( item ) => {
  return filterMenu.every(( filter ) => {
    const { group, key, value } = filter.filterKey;
    
    return item[group][key] === value;
  });
});
                 
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you! - This is exactly the solution, thank you so much for this :) - Been racking my head all morning, it's just one of them days!